# App runs on iphone 5 like iphone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have finally done to build Augmented Reality app.

The app works great for iphone 4 screen size Width :480 Height :320.
During the development I have also test the simulator to see launch goes well for 4 inch display (iphone 5), and it did go well the splash screen show was the 4 inch png named : `Default-568h@2x.png` and the screen shows a white background fully (like it should).

When I launch the app on a real iphone 5 device, the 3.5 inch splash screen loaded and the app load like it loads on iphone 4. Everything in the middle and I get a little black equal Margins from the side, the cable is original and this is the Weirdest thing ever happened to me.

UPDATE : i have also tried to add this code on the simulator and to the real device :

```
CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(bounds));
```

the simulator prints iphone 5 screen size, the real device prints iphone 4 size.

Any help please

Comment: Try deleting the app on the phone and restart?

Comment: yes, i have try to delete the app. on xcode to make Product -> Clean
also restarted the mac and the iphone. nothing helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have **all three Launch images** set up correctly. :)

Comment: This is it.  If you have 2 launch images, but not one for the 4" display, the app will force itself to 3" size.  Buggy, but true.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image has been added to the target. 
=> If you select your image file in the Project Navigator (left pane) the Utilities pane (right pane) should have a checkmark under 'Target Membership' next to your target.

Comment: Alternatively, with the project selected, select your target then the Summary tab. Drag your image into the correct spot in the 'Launch Images' section.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your views need to resize. You may need to include some code that detects what device the person is using and resizes the view. Just a suggestion.